# pyqt5 tablewidget in tabwidget

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qtabwidget, qsettings

Хочу сделать приложение с несколькими вкладками, создаваемыми с помощью кнопки, как в вопросе [**передача переменной между классами**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1309675)

Данные в `tablewidget` заполняются из базы данных. При нажатии на кнопки должны извлекаться данные из таблицы, но данные извлекаются из таблицы, расположенной на последней вкладке.

Это фрагмент кода, который должен получать данные из таблицы на текущей вкладке. Но данные извлекаются только из последней.

```
index = self.win.rutinaGui.tabWidget.currentIndex()

self.win.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')
keys = self.win.settings.allKeys()

for key in keys:

    if key == str(index):
        indexColumn = (self.win.tabPage.tableWidget.selectionModel().currentIndex())

        tableData = indexColumn.sibling(indexColumn.row(), 0).data()
        print(tableData)
        nameDB = self.win.settings.value(str(index))

        data = self.db.editDB(nameDB, tableData)

        for item in data:
            self.Edit.labelInv.setText(item[2])
            self.Edit.lebelISN.setText(item[3])
```

**UPDATE**
Ну, 4 часа потратил, чтоб сделать "минимальный воспроизводимый код". Надеюсь, что кто-нибудь обратит внимание и подскажет.
Итак, первое, что нужно будет сделать - добавить вкладку (нужно будет задать имя вкладки и имя базы данных), затем добавить строки в таблицу. И всё тоже самое. При нажатии на кнопку "Изменить" из таблицы подтягиваются данные только из последней вкладки. 
Что делать - не знаю. Прошу помощи.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
import sqlite3 as sql


class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent

        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Номер АРМ', 'Инвентарный номер'])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(150)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.db = DB()
        self.table = MyTab()

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        count = self.tabWidget.count()
        self.nb = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text="Добавить", autoRaise=True)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(count, QtWidgets.QWidget(), "")
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(count, QtWidgets.QTabBar.RightSide, self.nb)

        self.btnAddRow = QtWidgets.QPushButton('ДОбавить')
        self.btnExit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выход')
        self.btnEdit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Изменить')

        self.settings = QSettings('tabsettings.ini', QSettings.IniFormat)

        self.tabWidget.tabBarClicked.connect(self.handle_tabbar_clicked)

        self.nb.clicked.connect(self.addDialog)

        self.btnEdit.clicked.connect(self.editDialog)

        self.btnAddRow.clicked.connect(self.addRowDialog)
        self.btnExit.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btnAddRow)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btnEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btnExit)
        self.loadTabs()

    def new_tab(self, tabName, nameDB):
        index = self.tabWidget.count() - 1

        tabPage = MyTab(self)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, tabPage, f"{tabName}")
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')
        self.settings.setValue(str(index), nameDB)
        self.settings.endGroup()
        self.db.createDB(nameDB)
        with open("tablist", "a", encoding='utf-8') as fn:
            fn.write(tabName + '\n')

    def loadTabs(self):
        with open("tablist", "r", encoding='utf-8') as fn:
            tabNames = fn.read().splitlines()

            for tabName in tabNames:
                index = self.tabWidget.count() - 1
                self.tabPage = MyTab()
                self.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')

                nameDB = self.settings.value(str(index))

                self.settings.endGroup()
                self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, self.tabPage, f"{tabName}")

                try:
                    data = self.db.viewRecords(nameDB)

                    self.tabPage.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(data))
                    for row, items in enumerate(data):
                        self.tabPage.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
                        self.tabPage.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))
                except(TypeError):
                    None
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def updateTable(self):
        index = self.tabWidget.currentIndex()
        nameDB = self.settings.value(str(index))

        data = self.db.viewRecords(nameDB)

        self.tabPage.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(data))
        for row, items in enumerate(data):
            self.tabPage.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
            self.tabPage.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))

    def addDialog(self):
        self.d = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.d.setWindowTitle("Добавить вкладку")
        self.d.setFixedSize(400, 150)

        self.tabNameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Имя Вкладки", self.d)
        self.tabNameLabel.move(10, 10)

        self.tableNameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Имя базы данных", self.d)
        self.tableNameLabel.move(10, 50)

        self.tabName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.d)
        self.tabName.move(180, 10)

        self.nameDB = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.d)
        self.nameDB.move(180, 50)

        self.pbAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Добавить", self.d)
        self.pbAdd.move(200, 100)

        self.pbClose = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Закрыть", self.d)
        self.pbClose.move(300, 100)

        self.pbAdd.clicked.connect(lambda: self.new_tab(self.tabName.text(), self.nameDB.text()) or
                                           self.d.close())
        self.pbClose.clicked.connect(self.d.close)

        self.d.exec_()

    def addRowDialog(self):
        self.d = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.d.setWindowTitle("Добавить строку")
        self.d.setFixedSize(400, 150)

        self.labelARM = QtWidgets.QLabel('Номер АРМ', self.d)
        self.labelARM.move(10, 10)
        self.leARM = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.d)
        self.leARM.move(180, 10)

        self.labelInv = QtWidgets.QLabel('Инвентарный номер', self.d)
        self.labelInv.move(10, 40)
        self.leInv = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.d)
        self.leInv.move(180, 40)

        self.btnClose = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Закрыть', self.d)
        self.btnClose.move(200, 80)

        self.btnSave = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Сохранить', self.d)
        self.btnSave.move(100, 80)

        self.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')
        index = self.tabWidget.currentIndex()
        nameDB = self.settings.value(str(index))

        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(lambda: self.addRow(nameDB) or self.d.close())
        self.btnClose.clicked.connect(self.d.close)

        self.d.exec_()

    def addRow(self, nameDB):
        arm = self.leARM.text()
        number_inv = self.leInv.text()

        self.db.insertDataMain(nameDB, arm, number_inv)
        self.updateTable()

    def editDialog(self):
        self.d = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.d.setWindowTitle("Окно")
        self.d.setFixedSize(400, 150)

        self.btnClose = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Закрыть', self.d)
        self.btnClose.move(200, 80)

        self.labelInv = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.d)
        self.labelInv.move(10, 40)
        self.labelARM = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.d)
        self.labelARM.move(10, 10)

        index = self.tabWidget.currentIndex()
        self.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')
        keys = self.settings.allKeys()

        for key in keys:

            if key == str(index):
                indexColumn = (self.tabPage.tableWidget.selectionModel().currentIndex())

                tableData = indexColumn.sibling(indexColumn.row(), 0).data()
                nameDB = self.settings.value(str(index))
                print(tableData)
                data = self.db.editDB(nameDB, tableData)

                for item in data:

                    self.labelARM.setText(item[1])
                    self.labelInv.setText(item[2])

        self.settings.endGroup()

        self.btnClose.clicked.connect(self.d.close)

        self.d.exec_()

    def handle_tabbar_clicked(self, index):
        self.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')
        keys = self.settings.allKeys()
        for key in keys:
            if index == int(key):
                value = self.settings.value(key)
                print(value)
        self.settings.endGroup()


class DB():
    def createDB(self, nameDB):

        self.conn = sql.connect(nameDB + ".db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main (table_id integer primary key, arm text, number_inv text)''')
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

    def insertDataMain(self, nameDB, arm, number_inv):
        self.conn = sql.connect(nameDB + ".db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute('''INSERT INTO main (arm, number_inv) VALUES (?, ?)''', (arm, number_inv))
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

    def viewRecords(self, nameDB):
        self.conn = sql.connect(nameDB + ".db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute('''SELECT arm, number_inv FROM main''')
        result = self.c.fetchall()

        self.conn.close()
        return result

    def editDB(self, nameDB, value):
        self.conn = sql.connect(nameDB + ".db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute('''SELECT * from main WHERE arm=?''', (value,))
        resault = self.c.fetchall()
        return resault


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Tahoma", 10))

    win = MyWindow()
    win.resize(950, 600)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick, код добавил, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не простой для понимания код и я конечно не проверял его полностью.

Основная идея моего предложения в создании словаря `self.tabPages = {}`, в котором будем сохранять экземпляры класса `MyTab()`

```
        ...
            self.tabPage = MyTab()
            ...             
            self.tabPages[index] = self.tabPage  
        ...
```

Я отметил строки, которые изменил. Я закомментировал строки, которые не понял зачем они нужны.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
import sqlite3 as sql


class DB():
    def createDB(self, nameDB):
        self.conn = sql.connect(nameDB + ".db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS main (table_id integer primary key, arm text, number_inv text)''')
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

    def insertDataMain(self, nameDB, arm, number_inv):
        self.conn = sql.connect(nameDB + ".db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute('''INSERT INTO main (arm, number_inv) VALUES (?, ?)''', (arm, number_inv))
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

    def viewRecords(self, nameDB):
        self.conn = sql.connect(nameDB + ".db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute('''SELECT arm, number_inv FROM main''')
        result = self.c.fetchall()
        self.conn.close()
        return result

    def editDB(self, nameDB, value):
        self.conn = sql.connect(nameDB + ".db")
        self.c = self.conn.cursor()
        self.c.execute('''SELECT * from main WHERE arm=?''', (value,))
        resault = self.c.fetchall()
        return resault
        

class MyTab(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTab, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(0, 2)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Номер АРМ', 'Инвентарный номер'])
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(150)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(self.tableWidget)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.db = DB()
# ??? 
# ???         self.table = MyTab()                           # ???        

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        count = self.tabWidget.count()
        self.nb = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text="Добавить Вкладку", autoRaise=True)
        self.nb.clicked.connect(self.addDialog)        
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(count, QtWidgets.QWidget(), "")
        self.tabWidget.tabBar().setTabButton(count, QtWidgets.QTabBar.RightSide, self.nb)

# ???        self.tabWidget.tabBarClicked.connect(self.handle_tabbar_clicked)
        
        self.btnAddRow = QtWidgets.QPushButton('ДОбавить')
        self.btnAddRow.clicked.connect(self.addRowDialog)
        self.btnEdit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Изменить')
        self.btnEdit.clicked.connect(self.editDialog)
        self.btnExit = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Выход')
        self.btnExit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        
        self.settings = QSettings('tabsettings.ini', QSettings.IniFormat)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btnAddRow)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btnEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.btnExit)

        self.loadTabs()

    def new_tab(self, tabName, nameDB):
        index = self.tabWidget.count() - 1

        tabPage = MyTab(self)
        self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, tabPage, f"{tabName}")
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')
        self.settings.setValue(str(index), nameDB)
        self.settings.endGroup()
        self.db.createDB(nameDB)
        with open("tablist", "a", encoding='utf-8') as fn:
            fn.write(tabName + '\n')
# !!! +++            
        self.tabPages[index] = tabPage                                # !!! +++

    def loadTabs(self):
        with open("tablist", "r", encoding='utf-8') as fn:
            tabNames = fn.read().splitlines()

# !!! +++
            self.tabPages = {}                                        # !!! +++

            for tabName in tabNames:
                index = self.tabWidget.count() - 1

                self.tabPage = MyTab()
                self.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')

                nameDB = self.settings.value(str(index))

                self.settings.endGroup()
                self.tabWidget.insertTab(index, self.tabPage, f"{tabName}")
                
# !!! +++               
                self.tabPages[index] = self.tabPage                   # !!! +++

                try:
                    data = self.db.viewRecords(nameDB)

                    self.tabPage.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(data))
                    for row, items in enumerate(data):
                        self.tabPage.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
                        self.tabPage.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))
                except(TypeError):
                    None
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

# !!! + ---------->       vvvvvv
    def updateTable(self, nameDB):
        index = self.tabWidget.currentIndex()
        
#        nameDB = self.settings.value(str(index))
        
        data = self.db.viewRecords(nameDB)

#        self.tabPage.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(data))
# !!! + vvvvvvv
        tabPage = self.tabPages.get(index)                               # !!! +++
        tabPage.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(data))
                
        for row, items in enumerate(data):
#            self.tabPage.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(items[0]))
#            self.tabPage.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))
# +++       vvvvvvv
            tabPage.tableWidget.setItem(row, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[0])))
            tabPage.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(items[1])))

    def addDialog(self):
        self.d = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.d.setWindowTitle("Добавить вкладку")
        self.d.setFixedSize(400, 150)
        self.tabNameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Имя Вкладки", self.d)
        self.tabNameLabel.move(10, 10)
        self.tableNameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("Имя базы данных", self.d)
        self.tableNameLabel.move(10, 50)
        self.tabName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.d)
        self.tabName.move(180, 10)
        self.nameDB = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.d)
        self.nameDB.move(180, 50)
        self.pbAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Добавить", self.d)
        self.pbAdd.move(200, 100)
        self.pbClose = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Закрыть", self.d)
        self.pbClose.move(300, 100)
        self.pbAdd.clicked.connect(lambda: self.new_tab(self.tabName.text(), self.nameDB.text()) or
                                           self.d.close())
        self.pbClose.clicked.connect(self.d.close)
        self.d.exec_()

    def addRowDialog(self):
        self.d = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.d.setWindowTitle("Добавить строку")
        self.d.setFixedSize(400, 150)
        self.labelARM = QtWidgets.QLabel('Номер АРМ', self.d)
        self.labelARM.move(10, 10)
        self.leARM = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.d)
        self.leARM.move(180, 10)
        self.labelInv = QtWidgets.QLabel('Инвентарный номер', self.d)
        self.labelInv.move(10, 40)
        self.leInv = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.d)
        self.leInv.move(180, 40)
        self.btnClose = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Закрыть', self.d)
        self.btnClose.clicked.connect(self.d.close)
        self.btnClose.move(200, 80)
        self.btnSave = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Сохранить', self.d)
        self.btnSave.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.addRow(nameDB) or self.d.close())
        self.btnSave.move(100, 80)

        self.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')
        index = self.tabWidget.currentIndex()
        nameDB = self.settings.value(str(index))
# !!! +++
        self.settings.endGroup()                                    # !!! +++
        
        self.d.exec_()

    def addRow(self, nameDB):
        arm = self.leARM.text()
        number_inv = self.leInv.text()

        self.db.insertDataMain(nameDB, arm, number_inv)
# +++                    vvvvvv
        self.updateTable(nameDB)

    def editDialog(self):
        self.d = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.d.setWindowTitle("Окно")
        self.d.setFixedSize(400, 150)
        self.btnClose = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Закрыть', self.d)
        self.btnClose.move(200, 80)
        self.labelInv = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.d)
        self.labelInv.move(10, 40)
        self.labelARM = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.d)
        self.labelARM.move(10, 10)

        index = self.tabWidget.currentIndex()
        
        self.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')
        keys = self.settings.allKeys()
        
        for key in keys:
            if key == str(index):
#                indexColumn = (self.tabPage.tableWidget.selectionModel().currentIndex())
# !!! +++
                tabPage = self.tabPages.get(index)                     # !!! +++
# !!! +++                
                indexColumn = (tabPage.tableWidget.selectionModel().currentIndex())                
                

                tableData = indexColumn.sibling(indexColumn.row(), 0).data()
                nameDB = self.settings.value(str(index))
                data = self.db.editDB(nameDB, tableData)

                for item in data:
                    self.labelARM.setText(item[1])
                    self.labelInv.setText(item[2])

        self.settings.endGroup()
        self.btnClose.clicked.connect(self.d.close)
        self.d.exec_()

# ??? # ???
    '''
    def handle_tabbar_clicked(self, index):
        self.settings.beginGroup('Tabs')
        keys = self.settings.allKeys()
        print(f'\nhandle_tabbar_clicked(self, index): self.settings.allKeys() = {keys}') #
        for key in keys:
            if index == int(key):
                value = self.settings.value(key)                           # ??? 
                print(f'value={value}; index={index}')
        self.settings.endGroup()
    '''
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Tahoma", 10))

    win = MyWindow()
    win.resize(500, 400)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**tablist**

Файл `tablist` - изначально пустой.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не переносил в основной код, но работает так, как задумывал. Большое спасибо! А про функцию  handle_tabbar_clicked() - планировалось по клику по вкладке загружать данные в таблицу, но еще не дошел до реализации и забыл убрать из кода. И про понимание кода - я не профи, делаю что то для себя в свободное время. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: @montfer пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: да, спасибо, что подсказали. стрелку вверх сразу же поставил, а галочку не замети